# Can't get my build to use the unirest-java-version of org-apache.http.client instead of the one shipped with Android (I'm at API 16)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, unirest

I'm having trouble with unirest-java on API level 16, namely I have compiled a JAR (`unirest-java-1.4.6-SNAPSHOT-withDependency-ShadedForAndroid`) with all dependencies and also some Apache-libs shaded - but I'm still getting errors about my app not finding `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase.releaseConnection`.

Which I have concluded is due to it using the built-in apache-libs (which didn't have the `HttpRequestBase.releaseConnection` implemented at API 16, only later on) instead of the ones I've compiled in with the unirest-JAR.

Tried building the project both using Android Studio (1.0) and Gradle but with the same result.

`LogCat`
http://pastebin.com/5MCSa7eg

`unirest-java/pom.xml`
http://pastebin.com/ThHZn3sN

`app/build.gradle`
http://pastebin.com/vNuguHCy

Any help in almost any direction is greatly appreciated!